# Why does quizzes have two zs

Tags: etymology, orthography

I didn't think I had to add an extra z when making it plural, but I did. Why is that? Just some weird anomaly like so many things in English spelling? Or is there a history behind it?

Comment: No, this one makes some sense.  You have to add -es to make plural a word ending in *z*, but the *e* will mislead people to pronounce the preceding vowel (here, the *i*) long unless the intervening consonant (the *z*) is doubled.  That is, *quizes* suggests it be pronounced kw-eye-zuz.  English spelling still won't make sense, though.

Comment: When you pronounce it, how many Z sounds do you hear?

Comment: @deadrat - Amen to that bit about it not making sense. (If it made sense, I'd be able to buy two topazzes, instead of two topazes.)

Comment: @J.R. But "topazes" only has one Z sound.  Probably something to do with the A vs I mouth position before the first Z, and how that affects the pronunciation of the final "es" sound.

Comment: @HotLicks - I don't pronounce the Z-sound in _topazes_ any differently from how I say the Z-sound in _quizzes_.

Comment: @J.R. - It's just that you pronounce two of them in "quizzes" but only one in "topazes".

Comment: @HotLicks - To me, they're inseparable in both words. No difference.